# Out of process memory error while executing left outer join

Tags: performance, memory

I am getting out of process memory error when executing the statement below in Oracle.

> Error : ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 16328
>   bytes (koh-kghu call ,pmucalm coll).

Statement executed:

x has 1 million rows and y has 3 million rows in the table. Please provide suggestions to fix this error.

```
SELECT NVL (ac.AC, 'U') AC, fd.b, fd.dt
       FROM x fd
       LEFT JOIN y ac
          ON     fd.b =
                    CONCAT (TRIM (ac.r), TRIM (ac.q))
                      AND fd.dt =  '31-DEC-2015';
```

Comment: Obviously, add more memory to your server. Also, if this question is about Oracle, please tag it as such.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the query to do a equijoin and a union of non-matching rows using minus and it worked .